# How to call new layout when there is no network connection?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, connection, android-manifest

Ok here is my problem:

I'm going to start new activity when there isn't internet connection, but new activity screen is black. New activity should show ImageView...

CHECK CONNECTIVITY AND START NEW ACTIVITY:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (info != null) {
    if (!info.isConnected()) {
    }
}
else {
    startActivity(new Intent(main.this, no_connection.class));
}
```

NO_CONNECTION ACTIVITY:

```
    package com.hello.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class no_connection extends Activity {


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.connection_error);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_verkkovirhe);

      }
}
```

AND HERE IS CONNECTION_ERROR LAYOUT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/connection_error" 
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:orientation="vertical">



        <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/verkkovirhe" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/image_verkkovirhe" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
        android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

OR

Maybe I can only change layout when there isn't network connection? When I try this I get force close?

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null) {
        if (!info.isConnected()) {
        }
    }
    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.connection_error );
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered that you have connection and you are not setting the other content view (which may be blank?)

i would also recommend this

`if (info != null) {
Log.e("TAG", "info != null");
        if (!info.isConnected()) {
Log.e("TAG", "info.isconnted() !");
        }
    }
    else {
Log.e("TAG", "setContentView");
        setContentView(R.layout.connection_error );
    }`

For logging purpose to figure out what is going on

Comment: if I change my code that it gives me force close?

Comment: What is the stack trace on the FC? I checked that code in my eclipse and there are no missing ';' or '}'.

Comment: btw your layout should not be the layout_id you call... Make sure your layout xml file name to connection_error.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting a new activity from a service you should use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. It should look like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, no_connection.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```